# fail to see what the difference is between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which should be the same

df1 is retrieved from a database, then:

```
df1.to_csv('raw data.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('raw data.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

(Even I don't use the parse_dates parameter my problem stays the same)
df1 and df2 have the same shape and also looks the same

But when I tried

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

I get False

Then with `df1.compare(df2)`

I get

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

what could be the reason the equals method returns False?

Comment: What is dtypes for `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: What do you get when you run `df1.eq(df2)`

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df1.head(5).to_string())`.

Comment: `parse_dates=True` means `read_csv` try to infer the column 1 (True == 1) as a `datetime64`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! the difference is in one column, one is having value NaN while the other with "None"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get clues by running

```
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

and see what the error message says

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html